# CURL return false only sometimes

Tags: php, api, curl

I have two servers, one gives API with endpoint, the other connect to first one via CURL

everything work fine, but sometimes curl return false.. if i try again .. it works again.

you can say if I stop send curl request for 2-3 minutes and back again .. first request will return false after timeout is over .. then second try will be okay..

this is really weird,,, could you please suggest me !!

**My Code:**

```
$params = array(
    "type"            => 'Get',
    "get_param"       => 'Installments',
    "language"        => 'tr',
    "client_ip"       => $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']

);

$api_url =  'https://blabla/portal/web/api/v1';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $api_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($params));
$response = curl_exec($ch);


echo '<pre>';
var_dump($response);
var_dump(curl_getinfo($ch));
var_dump(curl_errno($ch));
var_dump(curl_error($ch));
echo '</pre>';
```

**The response**

```
bool(false)
array(26) {
  ["url"]=>
  string(52) "https://blabla/portal/web/api/v1"
  ["content_type"]=>
  NULL
  ["http_code"]=>
  int(0)
  ["header_size"]=>
  int(0)
  ["request_size"]=>
  int(0)
  ["filetime"]=>
  int(-1)
  ["ssl_verify_result"]=>
  int(0)
  ["redirect_count"]=>
  int(0)
  ["total_time"]=>
  float(60.001051)
  ["namelookup_time"]=>
  float(0.004364)
  ["connect_time"]=>
  float(0.006517)
  ["pretransfer_time"]=>
  float(0)
  ["size_upload"]=>
  float(0)
  ["size_download"]=>
  float(0)
  ["speed_download"]=>
  float(0)
  ["speed_upload"]=>
  float(0)
  ["download_content_length"]=>
  float(-1)
  ["upload_content_length"]=>
  float(-1)
  ["starttransfer_time"]=>
  float(0)
  ["redirect_time"]=>
  float(0)
  ["redirect_url"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["primary_ip"]=>
  string(12) "82.222.47.39"
  ["certinfo"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["primary_port"]=>
  int(443)
  ["local_ip"]=>
  string(13) "37.230.110.12"
  ["local_port"]=>
  int(54335)
}
int(28)
string(71) "Operation timed out after 0 milliseconds with 0 out of 0 bytes received"
```

Comment: increase the time here and check:- `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);`

Comment: it was 60 seconds .. same results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is resolved from the hosting company of the endpoint server

- It is **not** the curl issue
- it is **not** DB engine of endpoint server
- It is **not** SSL issue

The `firewall` was blocking sometimes the requests, hope it can help someone later